# In Hyperledger Fabric Composer, how do you retrieve an attribute of the invoker of a function?

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I was able to write a Hyperledger chaincode that retrieves an attribute of the invoker of a function:

```
myRole := stub.ReadCertAttribute("role")
```

Currently, I'm studying the Hyperledger Fabric Composer.

I want to edit the logic file (e.g., lib/logic.js) to also retrieve the "role" attribute.

May I know how this is done in Fabric Composer?

Answer (score 3):

You would use the `getCurrentParticipant()` runtime API function inside your TP function. This will give you the participant instance that submitted the transaction (or null if the cert has not been mapped to a participant). You will need to use the issue identity / revoke identity APIs or CLI to map from an encrypted cert attribute to a participant id.

See: https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/managing/identity-issue.html

Comment: Thank you Dan.  I'll try this.